# Two clicks to perform button action with requirejs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have this code:

#### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="lib/require.js" data-main="app"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="remover">Remove</button>
</body>
</html>
```

#### app.js

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'jquery': 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min',
        'mylib': 'applib/mylib'
    }
});

require(['mylib'], function(teller){
    teller.tell('Hello there');

    $(function(){
        $('#remover').on('click', function(){
            teller.remove();
        })
    })
});
```

#### mylib.js

```
define(['jquery'], function($){
    var tell = function(msg){
        $('body').append( $('<p>').text(msg).addClass('teller') );
    };

    var remove = function(){
        $('#remover').on('click', function(){
            $('body').find('.teller').remove();
        });
    };


    return {
        tell: tell,
        remove: remove
    }
});
```

I don't understand, why it takes two clicks for the button to remove the element. Could anyone explain to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your remove function in mylib.js doesn't also need to listen for the click because you are already listening to the click in app.js.

You can change your remove function to:

```
var remove = function(){
    $('body').find('.teller').remove();
};
```

Comment: That's correct, An oversight of mine. Still I don't understand what was happening :)